# Update a file in zookeeper with zkcli

Tags: apache-zookeeper

how do I update a file with zkCli without any third party tools? I can't seem to find any examples anywhere. I can connect to the zookeeper instance, create/delete nodes and etc... but can't figure out how to upload one file from the filesystem into it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with the standard zookeeper cli.  You can do that with [zk_shell](https://github.com/rgs1/zk_shell).  From their readme,

```
(CONNECTED) /> cp file:///etc/passwd zk://localhost:2181/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a command like this:

./zkCli.sh set /solr/clusterstate.json "`cat import.json`"

This is run from the Zookeeper bin directory.